# Error en peticion con fetch en js

Tags: javascript, c#, sql-server

Que tal comunidad buenas tardes. Tengo este codigo en js.

```
  let Url = "@Url.Content("~/Inventario/ListarExistencias")";
        fetch(Url, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify({
                IdUbicacion: cmbUbicacion.value,
                IdProducto: null,
                NombreP: null,
                Usuario: lblUsuario.textContent.split(":")[1],
                Todos: chkTodas.checked
            }), headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
        }).then((Response) => {
            if (Response.ok) {
                return Response.text();
            }
        }).then((Result) => {
            if (!Result.includes("ERROR")) {
                let Tupla = document.getElementById("tblExistencias");
                Tupla.innerHTML = "";
                let Existencias = new Array();
                Existencias = JSON.parse(Result);
                console.table(Existencias);
                Existencias.forEach((Existencia) => {
                    let Tr = document.createElement("tr");
                    Tr.appendChild(CreateElement("td", Existencia.Codigo, null));
                    Tr.appendChild(CreateElement("td", Existencia.Nombre_Producto, null));
                    Tr.appendChild(CreateElement("td", Existencia.Descripcion, null));
                    Tr.appendChild(CreateElement("td", Existencia.Presentacion, null));
                    Tr.appendChild(CreateElement("td", Existencia.Existencia_Minima, null));
                    Tr.appendChild(CreateElement("td", Existencia.Existencia, null));
                    Tr.appendChild(CreateElement("td", Existencia.Descripcion_Existencia, null));
                    Tr.appendChild(CreateElement("td", Existencia.Ubicacion, null));
                    Tupla.appendChild(Tr);
                })
            }
        })
```

El problema es que paso los datos al backend y llegan bien el problema es que no me retorna datos pero al momento de probar ese recurso en POSTMAN con los mismos datos si me retorna datos. Ya re programe la función pero sigue sin funcionar. Estoy seguro que funciona el backend por que funciona en otra aplicación de manera correcta.
Este es el código donde consumo los datos de backend. Es una funcion en C#

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ListarExistencias(int? IdUbicacion,string IdProducto,string NombreP,string Usuario,bool? Todos) {
            try
            {
                GestorInventario GestorExistencias = new GestorInventario(FuncionesVarias.Instancia.DesEncripta(Properties.Settings.Default.StringConexion, "Clave"));
                JavaScriptSerializer JSON = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                return Content(JSON.Serialize(GestorExistencias.ListaExistencias(IdUbicacion, IdProducto, NombreP, Usuario, Todos)).ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Content("ERROR: "+ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Espero me puedan ayudar y de antemano agradezco su tiempo.

Comment: Está dificil ver el error, lo primero es que pruebes cambiar esto en el body `IdUbicacion: Number(cmbUbicacion.value)`. Si esto no funciona, coloca un punto de interrupción en el controller y valida que estén llegando lo datos. Por último, también simplificar el `fetch` para encontrar el error `.then(r=>r.text()).then(r=>console.log(r))`

Comment: Hola Pablo este parece un error de CORS, como saberlo, cambia el metodo POST a OPTIONS  si te da error, debes agregar ese metodo, aqui una pagina para probarlo https://www.test-cors.org/

Comment: Gracias por su ayuda, lamentablemente no funciono, lo raro es que otras funciónes que consume el mismo backend si fucniona

Comment: Llega a la parte donde esta el datareader en otro metodo pero como que si la db no retorno nata y manda una lista vacia